# Showing specific results in different columns when self-joining a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, self-join

I have a table, email_activities_2, with a column titled "action_type", where results can be "sent", "open", "click", etc., and there is one record per action, per email, per recipient_id. For example, email_id 94607 for recipient_id 54 has two rows: one where the action_type is "sent", and the second where it's "open".

I want a query that will return that in one row, with the action_type column listed twice, but on the left, only showing action_type = "sent", and the right column being action_type = "open" or "null"

This is the closest I've gotten to what I want:

```
select email2.email_id, email2.recipient_id, email2.action_type as sent, 
opens.action_type as opened
  from email_activities_2 email2 
  left join email_activities_2 opens on email2.id = opens.id
  where email2.action_type = "sent"
union all
select email2.email_id, email2.recipient_id, email2.action_type as sent, 
opens.action_type as opened
  from email_activities_2 email2
  right join email_activities_2 opens on email2.id = opens.id
  where opens.action_type = "open"
  order by recipient_id, email_id asc;
```

This returns:

```
email_id    |   recipient_id   |  sent  |   opened

94607              54             sent      sent
94607              54             open      open
94981              54             sent      sent
98479              54             sent      sent
98479              54             open      open
```

When what I want is:

```
email_id    |   recipient_id   |  sent  |   opened

94607              54             sent      open
94981              54             sent      NULL
98479              54             sent      open
```

Is this possible? I'm brand new to SQL and trying to figure this out as I go.

Comment: You want to look into "table aliasing" to make a virtual "copy" of a table so you can use it twice in the query.  Setup a fiddle and post it if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL should do the job for you:

```
Select email2.email_id,
       email2.recipient_id,
       MAX ( CASE WHEN email2.action_type = "sent" THEN email2.action_type  END ) As sent, 
       MAX (CASE WHEN opens.action_type = "open" THEN opens.action_type  END) As opened
  from email_activities_2 email2 
  left join email_activities_2 opens on email2.id = opens.id
  where email2.action_type = "sent" or opens.action_type = "open"
  group by email2.email_id
  order by recipient_id, email_id asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want get all sent emails and their open activity (If they were open)
The Query should be:

```
select email2.email_id, email2.recipient_id, email2.action_type as sent, 
opens.action_type as opened
  from email_activities_2 email2 
  left join (
select * from  email_activities_2
where email_activities_2.action_type = "open" 
) as opens on email2.id = opens.id
  where email2.action_type = "sent"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be conditional aggregation, with no need for a join.

```
SELECT e.email_id
     , e.recipient_id
     , MAX(IF(e.action_type='sent',e.action_type,NULL)) AS sent
     , MAX(IF(e.action_type='open',e.action_type,NULL)) AS opened
  FROM email_activities_2 e
 WHERE e.action_type IN ('sent','open')
 GROUP
    BY e.email_id
     , e.recipient_id
```

The GROUP BY clause will "collapse" all of the rows with equal values of email_id and recipient_id into a single row. The conditional test in the expression in the SELECT clause will "pick out" the values of `'open'` and `'sent'` for each group. The MAX aggregate will choose the highest non-NULL value to be returned, and will only return NULL if there were no rows in the group that matched the condition.

This query has the potential to return a row like this:

```
email_id    |   recipient_id   |  sent  |   opened
94999           54                NULL      open
```

in cases where there is a row with `open` but no row for `sent`.

If you need to eliminate those rows, you could add a HAVING clause:

```
HAVING MAX(IF(e.action_type='sent',e.action_type,NULL)) = 'sent'
```

If you want to return all values of email_id and recipient from the table, even when there are no rows with action_type of `'sent'` or `'open'`, you could omit the WHERE clause entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show emails that have been sent (or the table only contains sent emails) a LEFT JOIN solution is just fine for two types.

```
select
    sent.email_id,
    sent.recipient_id,
    sent.action_type as sent,
    open.action_type as opened
from email_activities_2 sent
left join email_activities_2 open
    on  open.email_id = sent.email_id
    and open.recipient_id = sent.recipient_id
    and open.action_type = 'open'
where sent.action_type = 'sent';
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XKLK2585)